# Laravel pagination link doesn't work during empty input

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I am trying to show all data from my table in my laravel blade view.

**Controller**

```
public function search()
    {
       $search = request('show');
       $users = User::query();

       foreach ($search as $field=>$value) 
       {
             if($value!=NULL)
             {
                $users = $users->where($field, 'LIKE', '%'.$value.'%');
             }
        }
       if(request()->has('sort'))
       {
            $order = explode(',',request('sort'));
            $users = $users->orderBy($order[0],$order[1]);
       }
        $users = $users->SimplePaginate(15);

        return view('nabil.homepage',compact('users'));         
    }
```

**Blade**

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    <tr>
        @if(session()->has('show'))
            @foreach(session()->get('columns') as $column)
                @if(in_array($column,session()->get('show')))
                    <td>{{ $user->$column }}</td>
                @endif
            @endforeach
        @endif
    </tr>
@endforeach
</table>
{{ $users->appends(Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::except('page'))->links() }}
```

If I search something then it works perfectly. But if I search with blank value. Then it doesn't work. The first page comes without any problem but then it breaks.

**Case 1 (problematic case):**

I input an empty value in search. So the search url is `/search?show%5Bbango%5D=` .

However, when I click next then the url becomes `/search?page=2` (And returns error)

If I manually input `/search?show%5Bbango%5D=&page=2` in url address then it works perfectly.

**Case 2:**

I input some data like '123' in search. Then my url becomes `/search?show%5Bbango%5D=123` .
In that case everything works perfectly.

**Case 3:**

It may be irrelevant. But if I run query in more than one field then it works ok but somehow all empty inputs get removed from url when I use pagination.

I may try to search with two input fields (example: name and bango). If I keep the name field empty and put '123'in bango then the url becomes like `/search?show%5Bbango%5D=123&show%5Bname%5D=`.

However, if I try to go to next page. then the url becomes `/search?show%5Bbango%5D=123&page=2`.

Although, the showed results are good but url suddenly drops the name field.

How can I make sure that the pagination still works for empty input. I checked in some similar questions and tried appending query request. But it still doesn't work for me.

Comment: Try to use ```request()``` instead of ```session()```

Comment: But the generation of my table depends on what data  I have in my session. There can be ten column but I may need to show only two. That depends on the session value.

Comment: Can you share how you paginate the data?

Comment: Check the updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using foreach, it is expecting an array. Try to set

```
$search = request('show') ?? [];
```

on the controller.